How to ensure nonnull value using getter in Kotlin
I declared this variable in one file:
internal var globalScope: GlobalScope? = null
    get() = field!!

And in the same package, whenever I use this globalScope variable, it is still considered a GlobalScope?.

What is the best way to resolve this type conflict? Should I define another API that returns a GlobalScope?

Can you explain what your ultimate goal is? What are you trying to express with this code? Without any more context, the code doesn't make sense.

If the property is never nullable after being initialized, then perhaps using lateinit would better fit your needs.

In the above example we are trying to access globalScope field by using the get() method on that field. When we use this get() method the return type must  match with the field return type that's why you are getting GlobalScope? as the return type.
Problem Statement: We need to throw an error when we try to access the globalScope field before initialization.
To achieve this we can use lateinit modifier for globalScope field. Accessing a lateinit property before it has been initialized throws a special exception that clearly identifies the property being accessed and the fact that it hasn't been initialized.
After initialization of globlaScope field you can access without any error. The code will look like this
internal lateinit var globalScope: GlobalScope

This is a Player class that has globalScope with lateinit modifier
A error is thrown as we are trying to access globalScope before initialization
Here, we initialized globalScope before accessing, so there will be no error
I hope this solves your problem.
